# Gatling does not send metrics to InfluxDB using graphite protocol

Tags: influxdb, graphite, gatling, scala-gatling

I followed the [BlazeMeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-tests-monitoring-with-grafana-and-influxdb?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=how-to-create-a-lightweight-performance-monitoring-solution-with-docker-grafana-and-influxdb) to monitor Gatling tests with Grafana and InfluxDB but no data is sent to InfluxDB and not any database created with the name "graphite".
InfluxDB is up and listen to port :2003. This is the log from InfluxDB:

```
2018-06-24T09:48:17Z Listening on TCP: [::]:2003 service=graphite addr=:2003
```

And I set `gatling.conf` fields to these:

```
  data {
    #writers = [console, file]      # The list of DataWriters to which Gatling write simulation data (currently supported : console, file, graphite, jdbc)
    console {
      #light = false                # When set to true, displays a light version without detailed request stats
    }
    file {
      #bufferSize = 8192            # FileDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
    }
    leak {
      #noActivityTimeout = 30  # Period, in seconds, for which Gatling may have no activity before considering a leak may be happening
    }
    graphite {
      light = false              # only send the all* stats
      host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
      port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
      protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
      rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
      bufferSize = 8192          # GraphiteDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
      writeInterval = 1          # GraphiteDataWriter's write interval, in seconds
    }
  }
```

`gatling.conf` is in `src/test/resources` folder and I ensured that this config file is loaded by Gatling by debugging it.

What I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid data writers configuration. Set it to:

```
writers = [console, file, graphite]
```